# Изменить текст в кнопке Android

Tags: android, button, gridview

Проблема заключается в том что при добавлении кнопки в GridView с помощью ArrayAdapter<> и List не добавляется текст который я устанавливаю в button.setText("primer"); то-есть не отображается текст в этой кнопке. Отображается android.widget.Button(...)

Код MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

GridView FieldLayout;
ArrayAdapter<Button> adapter;
List<Button> list;
//LinearLayout Test;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FieldLayout = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gVDesk) ;
    list = new ArrayList<Button>();


}


// Заполняем в шахматном порядке.
public void Create(View v) {
    Button button = new Button(this);//(Button) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_btn_add, null);

    button.setText("primer");
    list.add(button);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.layout_btn_add, list );
    FieldLayout.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}}
```

Comment: Решил свой вопрос создав класс наследующий ArrayAdapter и переопределил метод getView(). В ArrayAdapter он меняет текст нашего объекта, поэтому необходимо было его переопредлить

Comment: Вы неправильно используете адаптер - ему не нужны кнопки, он сам их создаёт из `layout`, переданного в конструктор. Ему нужен текст для этих кнопок.